# Is the pinger really weaker at the back?

Tags: crysis-2

In the first Pinger battle, it's suggested that it has a weak point at the back, and you should concentrate your fire there. This is shown visually too, by the back parts being red, like other enemies' weak points. But when I attack later Pingers (in 'Soldier' difficulty), it seems that it takes 6 JAW hits to kill it, regardless of where I hit it. Is it just that I'm not managing to hit the right point? Does the weak point only make a difference at harder difficulties? Or perhaps the weak point only applies to bullet weapons, not the JAW?

What's really going on? I'm struggling on my Pinger battles (especially in 'Power Out') because I spend ages trying to get around behind it, seemingly to no avail. I'm on PC, with the non-Steam version, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

weapons with gauss attachment are effective agenst the pinger. useing the jaw is a quick way of dispatching them but if thats not an option you can do haveing four C4 pack attached uppon the pinger's weak spot in the back. But all the C4 has to be detonated at the same time if the C4 is detonated seperate it wont kill the pinger. As for the question title yes the pinger is really weaker in the back

for other strategies check the wiki

Source and wiki (stated above): http://crysis.wikia.com/wiki/Ceph_Pinger